# AHK script to open specific webpages

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I cannot set up a script when trying to use just part of the Window Title of a webpage using Internet Explorer or Chrome

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, bab.la Italian-English dictionary - Internet Explorer ahk_class IEFrame
!space::
msgbox hello
return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the title is not correct and you are trying to be too specific. Try

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Italian-English dictionary ahk_exe chrome.exe
!space::
msgbox hello
return
#IfWinActive
```